# MS Access join query returning more data than expected

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to join two tables, the left table has 7836 rows and I'm trying to return all of those rows joined with the customer's address that is in the right table (around 75000 rows). I am using this MS Access SQL query

```
SELECT
    ALL_SALES_REFUND.TRANSACTION_EVENT_ID, [Duplicates-removed].[recipient-name], [Duplicates-removed].[ship-address-1], [Duplicates-removed].[ship-address-2], [Duplicates-removed].[ship-address-3], [Duplicates-removed].[ship-city],
    [Duplicates-removed].[ship-state], [Duplicates-removed].[ship-postal-code], [Duplicates-removed].[ship-country]
FROM
    ALL_SALES_REFUND
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Duplicates-removed] ON ALL_SALES_REFUND.[TRANSACTION_EVENT_ID] = [Duplicates-removed].[order-id];
```

But it returns 8118 rows instead of the 7836, how can I modify it to return just the 7836 original rows?

Answer (score 0):

If this query returns more records than in `ALL_SALES_REFUND`, then obviously there are duplicate values in `[Duplicates-removed].[order-id]`.

If you don't want this, you'll need to use `GROUP BY ALL_SALES_REFUND.TRANSACTION_EVENT_ID` and aggregation functions on the columns from `[Duplicates-removed]`.

If both `ALL_SALES_REFUND.TRANSACTION_EVENT_ID` and `[Duplicates-removed].[order-id]` contain duplicates, then there is no way to avoid multiple IDs on the one side matching multiple IDs on the other side, creating more records in the process.

You will need to find a better JOIN criteria to avoid it, or remove duplicates on at least one side.

Comment: Hi Andre, unfortunately the `GROUP BY` means that the query returns less records than exist in the original `ALL_SALES_REFUND` (some sales with the same ID have more than 1 entry).

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of unique id in the second table.  Then you can do:

```
SELECT asr.TRANSACTION_EVENT_ID, dr.[recipient-name], 
       dr.[ship-address-1], dr.[ship-address-2], dr.[ship-address-3], dr.[ship-city],
       dr.[ship-state], dr.[ship-postal-code], dr.[ship-country]
FROM ALL_SALES_REFUND as asr LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     [Duplicates-removed] as dr
     ON asr.[TRANSACTION_EVENT_ID] = dsr.[order-id] 
WHERE dr.[order-id] IS NULL OR
      dr.? = (SELECT MAX(dr2.?)
              FROM [Duplicates-removed] as dr2
              WHERE dr2.[order-id] = dr.[order-id]
             );
```

The `?` is for the column that specifies which row to get -- perhaps an id or date column.